Laravel 10 Queued jobs not marked "done" but are processed
So, this is a strange one. I have a fairly simple job, gets a user model and deletes it. Granted, the user model has lots of relations and observers but for the sake of the issue i've disabled the observers. Another thing about the user model is that the relationships db tables are set to cascade on delete. Now for the problem itself, I queue the job, and its being picked up by the worker and its showing as Pending both at the cli as well in Laravel Telescope Jobs page, it is never reaching the Done stage. the job itself is processed fully and everything gets deleted but i cannot not wonder whether its an indication of an issue/problem. In laravel-beanstalkd-admin-ui the job is marked as processed btw. Its only happening with this job, all others are marked as Done.
Anyone has any idea what this might be and whether its an indicator of an actual problem?
Thanks
Well i've tried disabling any events and observers related to the model, tried only deleting the model itself without handling its relationships..
